# Minecraft multiplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

okay so basically I've played with friends while im at their house. Well if we live in the same city but far away is it possible to just do as you normally do and open lan then type in the IP, etc. Hahah I'm rlly stupid

Answer (score 1):

LAN Stands for Local Area Network. You need to be on the same network in order to join each-other with IP. I would recommend playing on a server or even setting up your own. This video shows how to